# how group_by keeping the datas in one row?

Tags: sql, group-by

The following table is the result of a join with

- id = customer_card_id
- nature_transfer = [ 1=>'arrival', 3=>'departure']

| customer_id | date_hour | nature_transfer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1115 | 2023-05-08 | 1 |
| 1115 | 2023-05-21 | 3 |
| 1116 | 2023-05-10 | 1 |

I would like to group_by customer_id but having an other table like that:

| customer_id | date_hour | nature_transfer | date_hour_2 | nature_transfer_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1115 | 2023-05-08 | 1 | 2023-05-21 | 3 |
| 1116 | 2023-05-10 | 1 | null | null |

I try group_by, concat(but i don t want a string), join, a temporary table  etc but i have no idea how to do it

Comment: Hi - please update your question (using editable text not images) to show the ddl for the table(s), sample data for them, the result you want to achieve based on that sample data and the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own

Comment: I had deleted images and used the tables instead

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It's `GROUP BY` not `GROUP_BY` - unless you're using some weird language extension?